# Intl.DateTimeFormat() returns incorrect date for UTC

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, datetime-format

I am following https://devhints.io/wip/intl-datetime

I am having a test where:

```
const text = Utils.dateToText('2019-05-18T16:00:00Z', 'en-GB')
expect(text).to.equal('Saturday, May 18, 2019, 16:00')
```

and a function:

```
dateToText(dateTime: string, lang: string[5]): string {
  const date = new Date(dateTime)
  let format = {
     timeZone: 'Europe/London',
     day: '2-digit',
     month: 'long',
     year: 'numeric',
     weekday: 'long',
     hour: '2-digit',
     minute: '2-digit',
     hour12: false
 }
 return new Intl.DateTimeFormat(lang, format).format(date)
}
```

Test fails with:

AssertionError: expected **'Saturday, May 18, 2019, 17:00 PM'** to equal **'Saturday, May 18, 2019, 16:00 PM'** (+ expected - actual)

```
  -Saturday, May 18, 2019, 17:00
  +Saturday, May 18, 2019, 16:00
```

So according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 Date specification, `Z` is a symbol of Zulu which is a Greenwich timezone. I would then expect that `2019-05-18T16:00:00Z` is still 4pm (16:00) for `Europe/London`. It is important that I am passing the date precisely in ISO format.

When I remove `Z` from the end of the date (which is allowed by ISO spec.) I am getting the correct result (16:00). However, I would like to keep `Zulu` time indicator as this is the way how my database stores the DateTime currently.

On my local machine, I am on Europe/London timezone. On my other machine, the test is passing correctly, however, on Gitlab CI it throws an error. It's clearly related to timezones...

Is there anything else that may explain why I am getting this discrepancy or something I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[British Summer Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time) runs from March to October and for dates during that time, if displayed using 'Europe/London' timezone they will be 1 hour ahead of Greenwich Mean Time.

So `Utils.dateToText('2019-05-18T16:00:00Z', 'en-GB')` (summer time) correctly returns

> Saturday, 18 May 2019, 17:00

While `Utils.dateToText('2019-01-18T16:00:00Z', 'en-GB')` (standard time) correctly returns

> Friday, 18 January 2019, 16:00

Note the difference in the time component. So the test is failing correctly.

Comment: Right, so presumably I should assume two cases in my tests: one for summer time and the other for standard time. I can't find a zone called `Europe/Greenwich` to obtain always the same result - but it seems I shouldn't display UTC but the zone defined by a user then.

Comment: Yes 2 tests cases sounds reasonable. Yes if you always want the same result it should be UTC, but a user timezone might be more relevant depending on whether your app should display times in UTC or browser timezone. That depends on the requirements really, certain data like log data may be better in UTC